# Generate Outlook appointment link in a classic asp web application for main browsers

Tags: firefox, outlook, asp-classic, calendar

I'm trying to create a link in my classic asp web page to add an appointment to outlook with some data when clicking on it. Firstly, to do a test, I created it in Outlook and save it in two formats, .ics and .vcs that after I linked in my page.

When I ran them I notice that .vcs doesn't work on Firefox and Chrome, and .ics doesn't work only on Firefox, So probably I'll choose this last one.

My question is, is there any other format or a way to open .ics files from Firefox? it doesn't recognize it nor open the Outlook window.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

found this solution over on [Experts-Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23178137/Created-and-Send-a-Meeting-Request-in-ASP-to-Open-with-Outlook-Appointment-Calendar.html#a20951323), full credit goes to them:

```
Sub createICS (sTitle, sDesc, sDate, sStartT, eDate, sEndT, sFName)
    Response.Buffer = True
    server.ScriptTimeout = 3000
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim iFile : Set iFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(sFName, TRUE)
        iFile.WriteLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR")
        iFile.WriteLine("PRODID:Microsoft CDO for Microsoft Exchange")
        iFile.WriteLine("VERSION:2.0")
        iFile.WriteLine("METHOD:PUBLISH")
        iFile.WriteLine("BEGIN:VEVENT")
        iFile.WriteLine("DTSTAMP:"&dateToUTC (DATE(), TIME()))
        Dim dtStart, dtEnd
        dtStart = "DTSTART:" & dateToUTC (sDate, sStartT)
        dtEnd = "DTEND:" & dateToUTC (eDate, sEndT)
        iFile.WriteLine(dtStart)
        iFile.WriteLine(dtEnd)
        iFile.WriteLine("UID:{A6DEF157-DFCE-40F4-AC77-217563191E7B}")
        iFile.WriteLine("SUMMARY:" & sTitle)
        iFile.WriteLine("DESCRIPTION:" & sDesc)
        iFile.WriteLine("SEQUENCE:0")
        iFile.WriteLine("PRIORITY:3")
        iFile.WriteLine("CLASS:Personal")
        iFile.WriteLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED")
        iFile.WriteLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE")
        iFile.WriteLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY")
        iFile.WriteLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0")
        iFile.WriteLine("BEGIN:VALARM")
        iFile.WriteLine("TRIGGER:PT10M")
        iFile.WriteLine("ACTION:DISPLAY")
        iFile.WriteLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder")
        iFile.WriteLine("END:VALARM")
        iFile.WriteLine("END:VEVENT")
        iFile.WriteLine("END:VCALENDAR")
    iFile.close()
End Sub
Function dateToUTC (sDate, sTime)
    Dim iHour, iMin, iYear, iMonth, iDay, tDate, tTime 
    tDate = DateValue(sDate)
    tTime = TimeValue(sTime)
    iHour = Hour(DateAdd("h", 4, tTime)) 'correction for US Eastern time
    iMin = Minute(tTime)
    iYear = Year(tDate)
    iMonth = Month(tDate)
    iDay = Day(tDate)
    Dim s : s = iYear
    if iMonth < 10 then s = s & "0"
        s = s & iMonth
    if iDay < 10 then s = s & "0"
        s = s & iDay & "T"
    if iHour < 10 then s = s & "0"
        s = s & iHour
    if iMin < 10 then s = s & "0"
        s = s & iMin & "00Z"
    dateToUTC = s
End Function



if request.querystring("a") = 1 then
    strPath = server.mappath("/temp.ics")
    Call createICS ("The Title", "The Description", formatdatetime(now,2), formatdatetime(now,4), formatdatetime(now+1,2), formatdatetime(now+1,2), strPath)

     'do your emailing stuff here and when you add the attachment to the code use the strPath variable as in above
end if
%>
<a href="/temp2.asp?a=1">Click Here For It</a>
```